# Twilio connecting to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ringdown

Tags: twilio-click-to-call

I am using Twilio APIs in my apps. I have configured my App in the TWIML APPS tab and configured proper Rest endpoints.

When I am dialing the Twilio phone number the calls always go `http://127.0.0.1:5000/ringdown/handle?sorry=&stack=%2B17033145109`
and not to the REST endpoints that I have configured.

Please advice.

Comment: This issue is fixed.There is a setting under TWILLIO NUMBERS tab in twilio.com where you see the  Rest URI under the Voice section

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed.There is a setting under TWILLIO NUMBERS tab in twilio.com where you set the Rest URI under the Voice section.
The Rest URI neeeds to point to your Application where you want Twilio to call your application logic.